# Remove empty rows from the database

Tags: database, mysql, content

I'm writing a script to alter the post content column in the database and I just notice it has a lot of empty rows, these seem to be deleted posts that now have no content or anything, I don't like them.

Could i just `DELETE from posts WHERE content = '';` without breaking anything?

The database has around 40k rows, i can't afford to break it, its backed up tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine those rows with empty content are more often then not revisions rather than trashed posts. To make sure you don't delete stuff you want to keep I suggest you add the `post_status` to your SQL, using `trash` and `auto-draft` as value - the latter are the revisions. Btw the table column is called `post_content` not content. So your SQL would look something along the lines of the following:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts
  WHERE post_content = ""
  AND   post_status = "trash"
  OR    post_status = "auto-draft";
```

You could of course use `$wpdb` and its [`delete`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#DELETE_Rows) method to achieve the same.

Comment: You probably want a `AND post_type = "post"` since it's quite common for custom post types to have empty content.

Comment: @totels You are not wrong, but it depends on, if you want to delete trashed posts and revisions only from the `post` post type or not.

Comment: The OP does say "seem to be deleted posts that now have no content or anything" maybe I'm inferring too much.

Comment: @totels Let the OP decide, could be the generic posts for all kind of posts or the specific for posts from the post type post.